# How to fix a video with changing exposures (I didn't know about A/E Lock until now!)

Tags: post-production

I was filming an interview. Everything was cool with the right sound, WB, shutter speed and focus, However, my subject kept on moving in his chair the exposure changed whenever he moves. Then I realized it was my fault for I should have lock my exposure.

I use Adobe Premiere for editing. Is there a way to have the computer auto average out the exposure for me?

[Here's the specific video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhK6fI_yJio)

Comment: Look for deflicker effects or plugins. Not sure what's there for Premiere. If you can't find anything then I'll suggest a third-party method, but it's best to do this within your NLE.